# running sql update query in java swing

Tags: java, sql, swing, derby

I have a swing desktop application that is 
connected to a derby DB.

I use native sql query to select all data from the table 
 Now I want to update the data in the table with native sql queries
 but first I have to retrieve the input data from the swing textfields.

I am able to use the `jtextfielld.gettext()`

to retrieve that data but how do i set these textfields data to 
 the update query since the sql query is executed as a string statement.

for example :

```
String sql = "UPDATE APP.REGISTRY SET LETTER_FROM ='Japan Motors' WHERE id = 7"
```

so how do execute this query from the swing interface.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at [PreparedStatements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) ?

> Although PreparedStatement objects can be used for SQL statements with
>   no parameters, you probably use them most often for SQL statements
>   that take parameters. The advantage of using SQL statements that take
>   parameters is that you can use the same statement and supply it with
>   different values each time you execute it.

See the linked doc and note in particular the placeholder capability (using ?s) that allows you to *safely* insert parameters in your SQL.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are new to JDBC and looking for a way to execute queries form Swing App. If this is a case, I will refer you to look at JDBC documentation.

In essence, you will need to get a reference to Connection object, then create a PreparedStatement using the connection and then then you can call executeUpdate() method followed by commit() method.

However, Please understand that you have very limited options for getting connection in a swing app. You will need to look at the usage of DriverManager for the way to get connection for a database.

Comment: may be my question was not very clear but I have already used the statement object with the DriverManager and what I want is a way to use an update sql query that will take parameters